# Two progressions of statements regarding collections of sets; are both necessary?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have rewritten this question to improve its accessibility.

Let $X$ denote a set and let $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$. We have the following sequence of statements of increasing strength.

$A(0)$. $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$ has a least element.

$A(1)$. For all finite $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$, it holds that $\bigcup \mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{A}$.

$A(2)$. For all countable $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$, it holds that $\bigcup \mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{A}$.

$A(3)$. For all $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$, it holds that $\bigcup \mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{A}$.

Note that each statement implies all previous statements. For instance, suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under finite unions. This is Statement 2A. Then since $\emptyset \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ is finite, it follows that $\bigcup \emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$. But since the empty union is empty, it follows that $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$. We have thus deduced statement 1A.

Now consider the following, related sequence.

$B(0)$. No condition.

$B(1)$. For all finite non-empty $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$, it holds that $\bigcup \mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{A}$.

$B(2)$ For all countable non-empty $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$, it holds that $\bigcup \mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{A}$.

$B(3)$. For all non-empty $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$, it holds that $\bigcup \mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{A}$.

This sequence is similar, except that we're no longer requiring that $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$. More precisely, we have that "$A(n)$ holds iff $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B(n)$ holds."

Now intuitively, the sequences are only "superficially different." Meaning that if we just restricted ourselves to studying one of these sequences, we would easily and systematically be able to translate this knowledge into knowledge about the other sequence.

So my question is, are there any non-trivial consequences of the distinction between sequences $A$ and $B$?

If not, then there should exist a theorem that says, "Essentially, we can study just one of these sequences, without loss of generality."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The valid logical statements (for a given type of structure) also form lattice, ordered by implication, so you should draw these 7 statements (e.g. A.4.$\Rightarrow$B.3., etc.)

The join of the empty set is the *least element*, that's why these lists differ in this argument: the second branch (I called them B.1.--B.3.) doesn't imply a least element (A.1.), try to find a small counterexample for that.

And about the question whether which statements we rather need, that's a subjective question, and you'll never know, which one would be useful in an exercise...

Comment: Yes I'm aware that lists are asserting different things, and I'm aware of the implications between the different statements; but my question is more to the subjective side of things.

Comment: For example, B1 says "finite non-empty joins exist." This is the same as saying "binary joins exist." But is this useful? Perhaps we're better off studying the consequences of A2, namely "finite joins exist" which just means "B1+Least Element."

Comment: What do you mean by '*useful*'? I would say, every clean knowledge is useful in a sense..

Comment: Well if every poset satisfying $B(n)$ has property $P$, then every poset satisfying $A(n+1)$ has property $P$, too. The converse is false. But what if there is something very much like a converse? Then we can just focus on one list, and not worry about both.